# Real-time share of code saved in local file

Tags: editor, real-time

My situation is to real-time share of my code with my audience with these requirements.

1. I would like to use code editor (C language) that works directly with my **local** file (quick `CTRL` + `S` for save, etc. – no copy & paste from web editor into local editor).
2. My audience can watch and **copy** my real-time shared code on their laptops. Just **read-only mode** – no update of my code. They have different OS, programs – I **don't want to force them to install** additional software. Probably, the best situation is that they watch the sharing code in their web browsers (without registration needed).

---

My investigation so far:

1. Atom with Teletype or Visual Studio Code Live Share look nice but require the same software on the side of the "watchers".
2. https://codebunk.com, etc. satisfy watching code in web browser but I can not directly work with my local file.

Comment: OP, http://firecode.io is a tool that lets sites collaborate with code live. The site has links to other sites that use Firecode. Try there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a simple single-page application based on https://firepad.io editor that I can hosted on some freeware hosting. One version is read-only for my audience and one version I can use to update the content.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a webserver on some VPS somewhere, and mount a directory in the DocumentRoot for the site to your local machine (I use Linux, so I could do this with `sshfs` as can Macs I think).  Keep your source code there, and you'll have what appears to be local-to-you editing of files that as you hit save they are instantly re-published to the website.  Your viewers could simply load the relevant files in their web browser of choice.